# compile-time constant StringFormat

Tags: c#, optional-parameters, compile-time-constant

I have a method for converting text to bitmap:

```cs
private Bitmap ConvertTextToImage(string text, FontFamily fontFamily, float fontSize, FontStyle fontStyle,
    StringFormat stringFormat, float MaxWidth, float MaxHeight, Color backgroundColor, Color foregroundColor)
{
    // some code...
}
```

I want to make all parameters optional except `text`, `fontFamily` and `fontSize`. However, I have no idea how to create a compile-time constant `StringFormat`. I want it to be like a `new StringFormat()` by default.

Comment: Make a new function with desired signature calling that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you can let `null` be the default value and then check for `null` and replace it with the value that you *do* want for the default.

This is easier to demonstrate with an example:

```
private Bitmap ConvertTextToImage(string text, FontFamily fontFamily, float fontSize, FontStyle fontStyle,
    StringFormat stringFormat = null, float MaxWidth = 10, float MaxHeight = 10, Color backgroundColor = default, Color foregroundColor = default)
{
    if (stringFormat == null)
        stringFormat = new StringFormat(); // Or whatever default you want.
    // some code...
}
```

Alternatively (and in many cases more flexible) have an overload that takes ALL the parameters, and then provide additional overloads with missing parameters that call the version with all the parameters, passing appropriate values for the missing parameters:

```
private Bitmap ConvertTextToImage(string text, FontFamily fontFamily, float fontSize, FontStyle fontStyle,
    float MaxWidth, float MaxHeight, Color backgroundColor, Color foregroundColor)
{
    return ConvertTextToImage(text, fontFamily, fontSize, fontStyle, new StringFormat(), MaxWidth, MaxHeight, backgroundColor, foregroundColor);
}
```

For your example, I think this second approach would be easier, since you have some other parameters (the `Color` ones) which cannot have a default value other than by using the `default` keyword.

If you want to check those values, do the following sort of thing in the constructor:

```
if (backgroundColor == default)
    backgroundColor = Color.Beige; // Who doesn't love beige?
```

This only works if you NEVER want to pass a colour with RGB and transparency values all zero, since that's what the default for `Color` is.

Comment: I found that I need the same solution for `backgroundColor` and `foregroundColor`.

Comment: Or I can use `KnownColor backgroundColor = KnownColor.Transparent` then `Color.FromKnownColor(backgroundColor)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could assign `null` or `default` and initialize `stringFormat` inside the method.

```
private Bitmap ConvertTextToImage(string text, FontFamily fontFamily, float fontSize, FontStyle fontStyle,
         StringFormat stringFormat = default, float MaxWidth = default, float MaxHeight = default, Color backgroundColor = default, Color foregroundColor = default)
{
   if (stringFormat == null)
      stringFormat = new StringFormat();

   // ...other code.
}
```

Comment: Is `default` for `StringFormat` equal to `null`?

Comment: @AmirSinaMashayekh Yes, `default` for reference types is `null`, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values), but you can of course simply use `null` instead.